# Android: Positioning in file (similar to fseek in C++)?

Tags: java, android, file, http

I'm trying to read some data from html file that I opened from internet using httpClient. I'm using `readLine()` function in loop for reading.

The lines I want to read start at 500th row. Is there a faster way to position at file?

Problem is that reading all that unnecessary data takes too long (almost 10 seconds to finish loading all).

Answer (score 3):

From the InputStream you can skip a number of characters using `skip(long n)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to cross 499 line terminating characters to get to the 500th line (as `getline()` gets a line terminated by `'\n'`, `'\r'` or `"\r\n"` ).

The definition of a line is the basic problem. As a line is terminated using the above terminators(standard definition in most languages), for any algorithm that skips `n` lines, the algorithm will need to discover `n` line terminators. This means that the input stream will need to be examined `byte/char` by `byte/char` to discover the terminators, which leads to the conclusion that while you can only skip characters, but you **cannot** skip **lines**. Here skipping means that data need not be examined (either in your code or in the library code), for eg. a random access file type `seek()` or a File Stream `skip(n)` operation.

Thus, you might want to rethink your data structures, or the need to skip lines.